# Image extending past container with grid

Tags: html, css

I did not have this issue before I attempted to switch to grid instead of manually placing everything. However, I am hoping someone can point out my issue. When I load the page my background.png is fine in the second container, but it bleeds from the first container to the top of the second, even though there is another section beneath it. Any tips are appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Iguana Removal</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Modak&family=Roboto+Slab&family=Six+Caps&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/iguanaremoval2.css">
</head>

<img class="BackgroundImage" src="images/iguanaBack.png" alt="Pixles Free to use picture of an iguana back.">

<header>
    <section class="headerGrid">
        <div class="headerHead"><h1>Our Removal Services</h1></div>
        
        <div class="headerHome"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="headerIguanaRemoval"><a href="aboutIguanas.html">About</a></div>
        <div class="headerRequests"><a href="requestServices.html">Requests</a></div>
    </section>
</header>

<body class="IRbody">
    <section class="bodyGrid">
        <div class="bodyHead">
            <img src="images/background.png" class="textBackground">
            
            <h2 class="underline">header</h2>

            <div class="headText">
                random text
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="companyFleet">
            <img class="fleetImage" src="images/2015_team1.png" alt="picture of our 2015 team and fleet.">
        </div>

        <div class="body2">
            <img src="images/background.png" class="textBackground">
            <h2 class="underline IRBHead">header</h2>

            <span>
                random text     
            </span>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
html{
    background: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    
}

header{ 
    background: navajowhite;
    position: sticky;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 10%;
    left: 1%;
    z-index: 40;
}

Body{
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 25px;
    grid-row-gap: 0;
}
/*img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}*/
.BackgroundImage{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -40;
}
/*******header********/
.headerGrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". headerHead headerHead headerHead ."
    ". headerHome headerIguanaRemoval headerRequests .";
}
.blank{
    grid-area: blank;
}
.headerHead{
    grid-area: headerHead;
}
.headerHome{
    grid-area: headerHome;
}
.headerIguanaRemoval{
    grid-area: headerIguanaRemoval;
}
.headerRequests{
    grid-area: headerRequests;
}
/*******Body********/
/*Images*/
.textBackground{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 1%;
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.fleetImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
}
/*mainbody*/
.bodyGrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "bodyHead"
    "companyFleet"
    "body2";
}
.IRbody{
    position: relative ;
    width: 95vw;
}
.bodyHead{
    grid-area: bodyHead;
}
.headText{
    margin: 1px 1px;
}
.companyFleet{
    grid-area: companyFleet;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
}
.body2{
    grid-area: body2;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using background-image for the background images? As for the grid, you could go with background images (which would not bleed outside of their containers) or set your img styles to have `object-fit:cover`

Comment: Hay king thanks for the pointer. I am getting back into html after years. Learning grids has helped clean up my code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).